# python list append gives a error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have `list = []` and I am adding an element to it using `self.list.append('test')` and I get this error - `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'`

The other list that I have defined `append` just fine, any ideas?

Comment: it seems that you have a function called list in your code..

Comment: I just put the comment as an answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you have a function in your code that is shadowing Python's built-in function named `list`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all,you cannot use in-built function 'list' as a variable name and second is that with function object we cannot use  append

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).